# Why doesn't future::wait() block

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, promise, future

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <future>


int main()
{
    auto pms = std::promise<std::string>();
    auto ftr = pms.get_future();

    std::thread([&](){pms.set_value("hello world");});    
    ftr.wait();
    std::cout << ftr.get() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

According to [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait), `std::future::wait` blocks until the result becomes avaiable.

However, the code above can't print anything. Obviously the main thread has finished before the thread of `pms.set_value` finished.

Why doesn't `ftr.wait()` block?

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look at std::async

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is not that `std::future::wait` doesn't block. The real problem is that you have a race condition between the thread that you spawned, doing it's work, and the destruction of `std::thread` (temporary) object in the main thread.

Because of that, `abort` is called in the destructor of `std::thread` if the thread is still joinable.

Working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    auto pms = std::promise<std::string>();
    auto ftr = pms.get_future();

    std::thread thread ([&](){pms.set_value("hello world");});    
    ftr.wait();
    std::cout << ftr.get() << std::endl;
    thread.join ();
    return 0;
}
```

Note, if you don't join the `thread` explicitly, you would still have the same race condition (since it's possible that `main` can do its work faster, than the `thread` can clean itself up.

Demo of working example: [here](https://ideone.com/JZpKL8).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can detach the thread and use `promise::set_value_at_thread_exit` rather than `set_value`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>


int main()
{
    auto pms = std::promise<std::string>();
    auto ftr = pms.get_future();

    std::thread([&](){pms.set_value_at_thread_exit("hello world");}).detach();    
    ftr.wait();
    std::cout << ftr.get() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```